# contour integral of log z

Tags: complex-analysis

if $C:z(t)=e^{it} (0\leq t\leq 2\pi )$, what is the value of the line integral $\int _{C}\log z dz$, where $\log z=\ln\left | z \right |+i\theta , \frac{\pi }{2}\leq \theta <\frac{5\pi }{2}$ ?I don't know how to solve because the argument of the circle and function is different.

Comment: $$\oint_{|z|=1}\log(z)\,dz=\int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2} \log(e^{it})\,ie^{it}\,dt=-\int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2} te^{it}\,dt=-2\pi$$

Comment: Thanks. but I don't know why t is in pi/2~5pi/2. because z is in the circle, so I think t is in 0~2π.

Comment: The parametrtization of the circle is $2\pi$-periodic.  So, the interval $[\pi/2,5\pi/1]$ qualifies.  BUT we need to cut the plane at $\theta=\pi/2$ to ensure that we are integrating on the branch that defines the logarithm.